# 2D ArrayList adding issue

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, processing

So I am trying to code a Tetris clone for a class and I am attempting to create an arraylist of the different pieces so that I can randomly generate new pieces in the game. For some reason I am unable to add my declared "pieces" (2D int arrays) to my array list. Here is what my code looks like:

```
    ArrayList<int[][]> pieces = new ArrayList<int[][]>(7);

    int[][] piece1 = {{0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0}};
    int[][] piece2 = {{0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {1,1,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0}};
    int[][] piece3 = {{0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,1,0},
                     {0,0,0,0}};
    int[][] piece4 = {{0,1,0,0},
                     {1,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0}};
    int[][] piece5 = {{0,0,0,0},
                     {1,1,0,0},
                     {0,1,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0}};
    int[][] piece6 = {{0,0,0,0},
                     {0,1,1,0},
                     {1,1,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0}};
    int[][] piece7 = {{0,0,0,0},
                     {0,1,1,0},
                     {0,1,1,0},
                     {0,0,0,0}};  
  void setup{ 
  pieces.add(piece1);
  pieces.add(piece2);
  pieces.add(piece3);
  pieces.add(piece4);
  pieces.add(piece5);
  pieces.add(piece6);
  pieces.add(piece7);
  }
```

And so When I run the line

```
currPiece = pieces.get(int(random(pieces.size())));
```

If gives me an out of bounds error saying I have no elements in my ArrayList.

Thank you so much! P.S I am coding in Processing 3 which is super similar to Java only slight syntax differences.

Comment: Have you called "setup"?

Comment: @AJNeufeld Processing automatically calls `setup()` for you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. In your case we need to see how you're calling the `pieces.get()` line. The code you posted looks okay, so it must be somewhere else. An MCVE will help us track that down.

Comment: If `setup()` is called by the processing automatically, are you sure it is called before your code which calls `pieces.get()`.  Stepping through the code with a debugger, or set a break-point to make sure it is called.  Or at the very least, add a `print` statement.  Also, ensure you haven't created a second variable named `pieces` that is shadowing the other.

Comment: @AJNeufeld You were right the code in setup was called after it was trying to get the value from the ArrayList. Thank you for your help!